# How to retrieve facebook user's friends email information with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

This is what I tried

```
if ($user) {
  try {    
  $my_access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();

  $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends',array('access_token'=>$my_access_token));
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($friends);
  echo "</pre>";
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
  $user = null;
```

}
}

But this code only return the list of friends & not the friends email id

even after setting the permission like User & `Friend Permissions`,`email` in the app configuration.

Any idea?

how to get friend's email addresses

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the email address of User's Friends. Quoting from [Email Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) documentation

> **Note**: There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends.